# What is the C# data type that allows complex and imaginary numbers?

Tags: c#, complex-numbers

I am creating a C# project which takes two user inputs of complex numbers and completes a mathematical operation on them. The problem I am running into is how to parse *i* as the square root of -1.

```
double operandA = 0;
double operandB = 0;
double result = 0;
string textA, textB;
string error = "The value you entered is invalid, try again";

private void plus_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    result = operandA + operandB;
}

private void Subtract_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    result = operandA - operandB;
}

private void mult_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    result = operandA * operandB;
}

private void divide_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    result = operandA / operandB;
}

private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textB = textBox2.Text;
    if (double.TryParse(textB, out operandB))
        operandB = double.Parse(textB);
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error);
        textBox2.Select();
    }
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textA = textBox1.Text;
    if (double.TryParse(textA, out operandA))
        operandA = double.Parse(textA);
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error);
        textBox1.Select();
    }
}
```

It works fine on regular numbers, decimals, and negative numbers, but I can't figure out how to do the value of *i* that I need. Can anyone help? It has been suggested that I use System.Numeric.Complex, but whenever I try to do this using "Using System.Numerics.Complex" or simply "Using System.Numerics", it says this type/namespace does not exist inside 'System'.

Comment: Where is `i` and code related to it?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit

Answer (score 7):

If you want to support operations on complex numbers, you should consider using `System.Numerics.Complex`

```
Complex c = Complex.Sqrt(-1);
Console.WriteLine(c + 1);
```

For documentation on this type see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Make sure to add the System.Numerics reference to your project to use this library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Complex in System.Numerics

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DonBoitnott This isn't a link only answer.  The question is asking for a data type.  The answer provides a data type (without needing to follow any links).  That the post contains a link, in addition, doesn't make it a link only answer.

Comment: @Servy While technically accurate, shouldn't there at least be some expectation of substance?  Otherwise, every question's answer could be "go lookup the thing".  Not terribly helpful in most cases.

Comment: @DonBoitnott If you feel that the answer doesn't contain as much information as you feel it should you're more than welcome to say as much, but that doesn't make it a link only answer, or the moderation actions that apply to link only answers.